# General clarification for derivative notation

Tags: derivatives, notation

I am a bit confused on the different notations of derivatives, could you help me clear it up?

**The following can be interpreted as:**

- the total derivative of f wrt x, or equivalently, the derivative of f(x) wrt x
- the partial derivative of f wrt x, or equivalently, the derivative of f(x,y,z) wrt x

$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx},\, f=f(x)$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial(f(x,y,z))}{\partial x},\, f=f(x,y,z)$

**now the above is different from the below, which is:**

- the total derivative of f wrt x, evaluated at the point a
- the partial derivative of f wrt x, evaluated at the point a, b, c

$\dfrac{df}{dx}(a)=\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}(a),\, f=f(x)$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b,c)=\dfrac{\partial(f(x,y,z))}{\partial x}(a,b,c),\, f=f(x,y,z)$

**however if we do a super contrived example and set a = x and a, b, c=x, y, z then the following equality holds (except super contrived, yes?)**

$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}=\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}(x),\, f=f(x)$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial(f(x,y,z))}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial(f(x,y,z))}{\partial x}(x,y,z),\, f=f(x,y,z)$

no, this is not how I normally write derivatives, and I am only bending the rules so far as to test the boundaries/semantics

---

Is the preceding interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind what you wrote *should* be correct, but

1. The notation you use is not the most standard.
2. In weird edge cases, what you wrote won't match up perfectly with what a calculus textbook or similar may write.

For point 1., instead of $\dfrac{\partial\left(f\left(x,y,z\right)\right)}{\partial x}\left(a,b,c\right)$, I think it would be more common, and almost certainly clearer, to write something like $\left.\dfrac{\partial\left(f(x,y,z)\right)}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)}$.

For point 2., if everyone is being a careful explicit mathematician, or if we're in a common case, then I think the answer to your question is "yes", the partial derivative is just "the derivative at an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$". However, this may have an exception in a weird case. [MathInsight](http://mathinsight.org/partial_derivative_limit_definition) has the sort of example I have in mind, although I've seen it elsewhere as well.

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3+x^4-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ extended to be continuous on the whole plane. Equivalently, $f\left(x,y\right)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^{3}+x^{4}-y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \text{ where defined}\\0 & \text{ if }\left(x,y\right)=\left(0,0\right)\end{cases}$. Then someone might write use some differentiation rules and write something like $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{x^4+2x^5+3x^2y^2+4x^3y^2+2xy^3}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$. But this is undefined at $(0,0)$, even though the $x$-partial at $(0,0)$ is defined and equals $1$ (in symbols: $\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=1$).

Comment: thanks for editing the thing for me, and for the clarification

Comment: @AlanL, did this answer your question? If so, you may want to accept it. If not, let me know if anything I said is unclear or if there's some aspect of the question I did not address.

Comment: Yes thank you so much